# Downloading an image works in 2.3.3 but doesn't work in 4.0 or 4.1

Tags: android, android-emulator, nullpointerexception, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, httpurlconnection

I'm downloaded an image from a URL and displayed in an `ImageView`. This example worked fine on 2.3.3 emulator but when I try it on 4.0 or 4.1, it crashes with the message:

> Unfortunately, AndroidWebImageExample has stopped.

The LogCat shows I'm getting a `NullPointerException`. Anybody know why it doesn't work on 4.0 or 4.1?

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String image_URL = "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_C5a2qH8Y_jk/StYXDpZ9-WI/AAAAAAAAAJQ/sCgPx6jfWPU/S1600-R/android.png";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView bmImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
        bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
        Bitmap bm = LoadImage(image_URL, bmOptions);
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }

    private Bitmap LoadImage(String URL, BitmapFactory.Options options) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strURL) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        URL url = new URL(strURL);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();

            if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return inputStream;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
<TextView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="hello"
   />
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/image"
   android:scaleType="centerCrop"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat

```
07-20 14:09:08.689: D/AndroidRuntime(1894): Shutting down VM
07-20 14:09:08.689: W/dalvikvm(1894): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
07-20 14:09:08.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1894): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 14:09:08.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1894): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidwebimageexample/com.example.androidwebimageexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 14:09:08.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1894):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
07-20 14:09:08.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1894):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
07-20 14:09:08.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1894):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
07-20 14:09:08.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1894):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
07-20 14:09:08.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1894):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-20 14:09:08.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1894):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-20 14:09:08.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1894):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-20 14:09:08.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1894):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 14:09:08.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1894):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-20 14:09:08.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1894):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-20 14:09:08.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1894):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-20 14:09:08.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1894):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-20 14:09:08.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1894): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-20 14:09:08.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1894):     at com.example.androidwebimageexample.MainActivity.LoadImage(MainActivity.java:43)
07-20 14:09:08.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1894):     at com.example.androidwebimageexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
07-20 14:09:08.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1894):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
07-20 14:09:08.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1894):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
07-20 14:09:08.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1894):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
07-20 14:09:08.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1894):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: You cannot run network operations on UI thread at 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're performing a (potentially slow) network operation on the main thread. If your target SDK is 11 (Honeycomb) or higher this will throw a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` on Honeycomb or above, because this behaviour can block the UI and lead to an unresponsive app.  Even on pre-Honeycomb devices [this behaviour is discouraged](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/responsiveness.html).

You could use an `AsyncTask` to get around this, loading the data in its `doInBackground(..)`.

Comment: Are you saying I should have both LoadImage and OpenHTTPConnection inside AsyncTask's doInBackground()? And return inputStream in onPostExecute()?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, InputStream is NULL and for this throws NullPointerExeption. in your OpenHttpConnection method, add in catch `Log.i("OpenHttpConnection",ex.getMessage());` and see why.

Don't block the UI thread, you must use AsyncTask, a Service or custom Thread.
You would like this class http://code.google.com/p/and-bookworm/source/browse/trunk/src/com/totsp/bookworm/data/HTTPRequestHelper.java?r=31.
In the constructor, pass a custom ResponseHandler and make operations you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should move network operations from UI thread to service or AsyncTask

You can read more here: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html